# high efficiency furnace 92% 120btu fresh air intake

Tags: hvac

Why is my goodman gm9s921205dn high efficiency furnace is having a strong suction through the fresh air intake 3"pvc causing flame to shut down the system, and shows error code EEO, then I remove the pvc vent off and it starts functioning normal without errors, please, explain, thank you.

Comment: First read the instructions and find EEO error.  What pvc vent do you remove, the pipe or outside vent?  Maybe it sucked a bunny rabbit down the pipe.